# Should I use API gateway as a proxy to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I'm learning serverless architectures and currently reading [this](https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html#Ui-drivenApplications) article on Martin Fowler's blog.

So I see this scheme and try to replace the abstract components with AWS solutions. I wonder if not using API gateway to control access to S3 a good idea (on the image the database no.2 is not using it). Martin speaks about Google Firebase and I'm not familiar with how it compares to S3.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless/sps.svg

Is it a common strategy to expose S3 to client-side applications without configuring an API gateway as a proxy between them?

Comment: What do you mean by "expose S3 for using its API directly"? Using API gateway as a proxy to S3?

Comment: No, I mean using its API without any API gateways. I've read that it's allowed to do so. On the image, clients send requests directly to the product database (no. 2)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. S3 is object storage, not a database. You can make S3 public if you your anonymous ppl to upload files into it (bad practice), but its not a database.

Comment: Yeah you right, afaik it has no inherent query language so the word database is not a case here. So, maybe the question would better to be "Should I use API gateway as a proxy to S3 in this scheme?"

Comment: The AWS Athena service lets you run SQL on data stored in S3. And if your data is simple enough you might not need a query language. You **can** use S3 as a DB but it’s probably not what you want and is only advisable for some narrow use cases. See my answer for an AWS suggested architecture which matches what Martin Fowler is describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - probably, yes.

But, you’ve made a mistake in selecting AWS services for the abstract in Martin’s blog. And you probably shouldn’t use S3 at all in the way you’re describing.

Instead of S3; you’ll want dynamoDB. You’ll also want to look at Cognito for auth.

Have a read of this after Martin’s article for how to apply what you’ve learned on AWS specific services https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/

Answer (score 2):

Aws S3 is not a database, its an object storage service.

Making S3 bucket publicly accessible is possible but not recommended however, you can access its objects using the S3 API either via the CLI or the SDK.

Back to your question in the comments regarding whether consuming the API directly from the frontend (assuming you mean using JS) is for sure a bad practic since AWS highly recommend you to securly store your API credentials (keys), and as any AWS API call should include the API credentials (keys) provided by AWS for your IAM user, then obviously anyone using your web application can see these keys.

Hope this answered your question.